# How to remove unpleasant whitespace before colon in Rmarkdown citation?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

In Rmarkdown I want to have [ASA style In-Text Citation](http://lib.trinity.edu/research/citing/ASA_Style_Citations_4.pdf), so I need colons after the year, like: "`(1983:578)`", with *no* whitespace before the colon. When I set the `:` directly behind the year, the citation is being eroded. I tried also to escape both the space and the colon with one `\` or two `\\` backslashes but this was no help. I also tried, according to [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155017/136969), to first, define LaTeX code `\edef\hc{\string:}`, second, set "`\hc`" for the colon: "`[@hawking_thermodynamics_1983\hc578]`" but it looks just the same and this also was not the trick.

Here is my reproducable interim solution:

````
---
title: Example
author: Author
output: pdf_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
references:
- id: hawking_thermodynamics_1983
  author:
  - family: Hawking
    given: S. W.
  - family: Page
    given: Don N.
  publisher: Communications in Mathematical Physics
  title: Thermodynamics of black holes in anti-de Sitter space
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 1983
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# Chapter
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983 :578]. 

# References
````

or alternatively

```
\edef\hc{\string:}

# Chapter
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983\hc578].
```

And this is the unpleasant outcome:
[image]

Does anyone have the clue?

Comment: (a) Does `[@hawking_thermodynamics_1983\:578]` help? and (b) despite it likely being waaaaay over my head I'd love to see this work when you've got it completed :-)

Comment: (a)Great, your magic worked again! Thought I had tried that–I shouldn't work that much, thanks! (b) actually just the hobby, I got the title wrong and just fixed it :D